# Winsock - wait with calling accept() until client is really trying to connect

Tags: c++, winsock2

I'm creating a server in C++ using Winsock API. I'm wondering if there is any possiblity to call accept() function only if some connection is actually coming, so I dont't have to block my thread on accept(). In other words, I would like to make my thread wait and call accept() function only when a client is trying to connect. Is that possible?

Comment: Use select() to tell when accept() will not block.

Comment: Or use the socket in asynchronous mode. Use `WSAAsyncEvent()` or `WSAAsyncSelect()` to have Winsock notify you when a new connection is pending.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Winsock, you could use the Microsoft-specific extension function `AcceptEx`. This allows you to perform the accept as "Overlapped I/O", which conceptually means that the accept runs in the background, and you can occasionally go in and check if it's happened or not, either by checking the `OverlappedResult`, or by performing a Wait on the OverlappedHandle. `AcceptEx` will also optionally perform the first receive.

Without writing all of the code and thoroughly testing it, something like the following should work:

```
// The following:
//   Has no error checking
//   Assumes sListen is a bound listening socket
//   Some other assumptions I've not listed :)

// Allocate space to store the two sockaddr's that AcceptEx will give you
// 
char lpOutputBuffer[sizeof((sockaddr_in)+16) * 2];

SOCKET sAccept = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
WSAOVERLAPPED olOverlap;

ZeroMemory(&olOverlap, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
olOverlap.hEvent = WSACreateEvent();

DWORD dwBytes;

BOOL bAcceptRet =
    AcceptEx(sListen, // the listen socket
             sAccept, // the socket to use for the accepted connection
             lpOutputBuffer, // where to store the received information
             0, // don't do a receive, just store the local and remote addresses
             sizeof((sockaddr_in)+16), // size of the local address area
             sizeof((sockaddr_in)+16), // size of the remote address area
             &dwBytes, // set to received bytes if we complete synchronously
             &olOverlap); // our overlapped structure

if (bAcceptRet) {
    // the function completed synchronously.
    // lpOutputBuffer should contain the address information.
    // sAccept should be a connected socket
} else {
    // the function didn't complete synchronously, so is the accept Pending?
    if (ERROR_IO_PENDING == WSAGetLastError()) {
        // in this case, our Accept hasn't happened yet...
        // later in our code we can do the following to check if an accept has occurred:
        // note that the FALSE tells WSAGetOverlappedResult not to wait for the I/O to complete
        // it should return immediately
        ...
        DWORD dwFlags;
        if (WSAGetOverlappedResult(sListen, &olOverlap, &dwBytes, FALSE, &dwFlags)) {
            // the accept has succeeded, so do whatever we need to do with sAccept.
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, that's a very quick, hacked-together bit of probably non-working, non-compilable code, but it should give you an idea of how you could do something similar to what you want, and where to look.

Incidentally, it's not technically necessary to set the `hEvent` parameter of the `WSAOVERLAPPED` structure, but doing so allows you to *actually* wait for the request to complete:

```
if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(olOverlap.hEvent, INFINITE)) {
    // The accept occurred, so do something with it
}
```

I will now wait for someone to point out the huge glaring errors in my code...